# Is symfony 1.2 compatible with PHP 5.4?

Tags: php-5.4, symfony-1.2

Is symfony 1.2 compatible with PHP 5.4?

We have an application which was built on symfony 1.2 and is currently running on a server with PHP 5.3.29 and MySQL 5.1.73.

We now have a need to upgrade the server to PHP 5.4. Could someone please confirm Is symfony 1.2 compatible with PHP 5.4?

Thanks.
Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the OFficial Documenttion of [Symfony](http://www.symfony.com)

http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-1-2-is-already-available

**symfony 1.2 requires PHP 5.2. It works best with PHP 5.2.4 or above. You might need to upgrade your PHP installation to take full advantage of all features and benefit from better performance.**

So, The upgrade of Server won't affect the functionality of your application.